# Journey Builder Activation Error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION;Required field is missing: rules;;Flow Save failed

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, visual-workflow, permissions, marketing-cloud-connect

Until Last Friday, I was able to activate my Journeys that had a **Salesforce Data Event as an Entry Source** without any problems and since then nobody has edited the user permission settings as far as I am aware of.

Monday comes and and I suddenly am not able to activate any of them...

No matter how simple a Journey is; as long as it has to look into Salesforce data, I get the same error down below↓

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION;Required field is missing: rules;;Flow Save
>   failed. Unable to activate the Journey, the Sales Cloud user may not
>   have correct permissions. Activating a Journey requires the Run Flow
>   and Manage Force.com Flow permissions.

Here are some of the permissions that the admin account I have connected to Marketing Cloud has:

- The User is an admin in both Salesforce and Marketing Cloud.
- The user  has Flow User checked on their user detail page (this
  wasn't checked before the error but I still was able to activate
  Journeys without   any problems last week).
- The user has Run Flows, Manage Flows, View   All Data checked on
  their profiles system permissions.
- The user has Marketing cloud related permission sets that are
  assigned to them. The permission sets do not have above permissions
  checked.
- The user has Marketing Cloud as a connected application in their
  profile settings.(I also did this after the error as a possible solution)

I can not think of any other solution anymore... I feel like I did everything possible and I'm still getting the same error.
Also, I can't find the permission **Manage Force.com Flow** in my Org anywhere. If this is a must can someone navigate me to find it? I am using Enterprise Edition.

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: Marketing cloud is on api v.46. Are you using any field that requires api v.48?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem.
It seems that sometimes a Salesforce data event while being activated duplicates the fields that it's supposed to check and causes a problem in the salesforce data event entry source in general.
So after it gets activated, other journeys are not allowed to be activated until this data entry problem is solved.
This is what was explained to us by MC support.

I hope this would be helpful for others with the same problem as well, if you're getting the same error above, make sure to check other activated salesforce data events for possible bugs first.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/129321)

Comment: My answer is not a "Thank you" answer but it's explaining how I actually solved my problem. SO it's basically the answer to my initial question.  Please don't just delete my answer without reviewing the real content just because it's starting with thank you.

Comment: I agree it's not a thank you post. Just fyi `Answers` are still not the correct place to thank people for their help. If you would like to thank someone, use a `Comment` on their post instead, and consider voting up their post.

Answer (score 2):

Have you recently changed the "Name" (API name) of a field/deleted a field in Salesforce that is used by any of your journeys (including older versions that are no longer active)?

I did this once and it caused any attempt to validate or activate any journey to fail. The particular field I changed was used in journeys that used Salesforce Data as entry events.

I believe the reason is that when you create these Salesforce Data entry events, it is creating a new version of a Process Builder called something like *JBSystem_[ObjectName]_Process* and adding the field. When you are in Journey Builder and click to either validate or activate a flow, it is trying to Activate this process in Salesforce. If it can't find one of the fields then it fails.

The fix was to either change the field name back OR create a new field using the old API name (which tricks journey builder into thinking the field exists). Once I did this, everything immediately started working again.

Also note that running journeys still seemed to work just fine.

Hopefully that helps.